# MySQL JOIN query syntax with duplicate field - "database.table.field"

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have these two MySQL tables inside the same db that I am making use of for a forum like website. My question is about the proper query to join a new field inside table "topics" based on the "user_id" link between the two.

Table "users", where field "user_id" is created upon registration, autoincremented:

```
USERS
╔═════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ user_id ║ username ║ firstname ║ lastname ║ etc... ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║       1 ║ JJJJ     ║ John      ║ Johnson  ║ etc... ║
║       2 ║ MMMM     ║ Max       ║ Maxman   ║ etc... ║
║       3 ║ AAAA     ║ Alex      ║ Aleckson ║ etc... ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Table "topics", where "user_id" is taken from the other table when any user submits what you would normally call a new thread on forum websites.

```
TOPICS
╔══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ topic_id ║ description ║     datetime      ║ user_id ║ etc ... ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║        1 ║ bla bla     ║ dd mon yyyy hh:mi ║       3 ║ etc...  ║
║        2 ║ bla bla     ║ dd mon yyyy hh:mi ║       3 ║ etc...  ║
║        3 ║ bla bla     ║ dd mon yyyy hh:mi ║       2 ║ etc...  ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

I can confirm connection with the db is established succesfully in PHP. The db name is "website". I am running the following query with no success, for what I;d like to be the result you see in the third table ( right joining the last field).

```
mysql_query("SELECT topics.user_id, users.user_id
 FROM website.topics
JOIN website.users ON topics.who_posted_hangout;");
```

```
TOPICS
╔══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════╦═════╦═══════════════════╗
║ topic_id ║ description ║     datetime      ║ user_id ║ etc ║ username          ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════╬═════╬═══════════════════╣
║        1 ║ bla bla     ║ dd mon yyyy hh:mi ║       3 ║ etc ║ AAAA              ║
║        2 ║ bla bla     ║ dd mon yyyy hh:mi ║       3 ║ etc ║ AAAA              ║
║        3 ║ bla bla     ║ dd mon yyyy hh:mi ║       2 ║ etc ║ MMMM              ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════╩═════╩═══════════════════╝
```

I used an example I saw somewher to write the query, but something doesn't make sense to me:

- Q1: In the example I used to write the query, why did he mention only 1 table where "FROM" when he actually selects data from two tables?
- Q2: In relation to the question above, wouldn't this query behave unexpectedly because user_id is a field in both tables?
- Q3: I saw you can select "table1.field1" with this syntax. In the past, I also saw "database1.table1" in the query too. Oh I am actually using this formatting/syntax in the query as you can see (considering "website" is the name of the db). Can you and SHOULD YOU at times, SELECT like this: "database1.table1.field1", precisely because "user_id" is duplicate, one in each table? - sublime text won't recognize "3-way.3-way.3-way" as proper syntax, because of the two dots.
- Q4: Lastly and just as importantly, why doesn't my query work, can you modify it if you know what's wrong please? :-/?

---

TIP: if you want to show tables like this in stackoverflow questions, please use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/, copy the unicode art result, and place it between `<pre> </pre>` tags.

Comment: In Q1, while he doesn't include website.users in the FROM clause, it is inferred by referencing it in the join.  By including the field in a join, the table is assumed to available to the query.

Comment: 1. The join on `website.users` allows you to fetch data from both tables.

Comment: 2. The columns are referenced by table name e.g. `topics.user_id` and `users.user_id`. If you just had `user_id`, you would get a query error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
'SELECT * FROM topics INNER JOIN users ON topics.user_id = users.user_id WHERE topics.user_id = the_user_id';
```

Comment: Isn't it `user_id`, not `id_user` :P?

Comment: @Matt yeah :p my mistake

Comment: It says "Unknown column 'the_user_id' in 'where clause' ".

Shouldn't that field be created automatically and then populated all from this query? I also tried to alter the table and add that field before running the query. This way, it wouldn't give me any errors, but the field values remain NULL.

Comment: That's just an example if you're selecting a specific `user_id`. Otherwise just run `SELECT * FROM topics INNER JOIN users ON topics.user_id = users.user_id`

Comment: oh, by "specific user_id", I assume you mean something like 3, or 17, right?

Comment: Guys guys, hang on a sec (sorry, I deleted that comment above because I thought we were done). I don't know how this slipped unnoticed, but that is not the query I need. I want the query to create a new field "username" in table topics and simply populate it with the data from "users.username", just like the graphic illustration. I am now thinking I was off by miles and it's not even the JOIN statement I need? Gosh I am tired, it's 4 am here, time just flew by.

Comment: ah, can we just take this to chat please?

Comment: @J.Doe Maybe you are looking for somethin like `ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD the_new_column_name datatype`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102188/discussion-between-j-doe-and-hail-hydra).

Answer (score 1):

In Q1, while he doesn't include website.users in the FROM clause, it is inferred by referencing it in the join.  By including the field in a join, the table is assumed to available to the query.

Q2:  The reference to user_id in both cases is prepended with the table name:  users.userid, topics.user_id.  If he would have used user_id without the table names there would have been an error.

Q3:  Yes ... you are correct!

Q4:  I'm not 100% certain what you want your query to select so I don't have a suggestion .. yet .. but if you explain a bit further perhaps we can help.

Comment: Thanks bud, I got your explanations for Q1 and Q2. 

Q3, so selecting like "database.table.field" is incorrect ? But what if I'm connected to two databases each containing a table with the same name? Running "SELECT * FROM website.topics.title;" in PhpMyAdmin gives me errors.

Q4: solved it with the help of these guys above, thank you all :D

Comment: Use "AS" for example:  SELECT t1.name, t2.salary FROM employee AS t1, info AS t2  WHERE t1.name = t2.name;  The AS function allows you to give a table a different name.  I use this to shorten table names but it can also be used to give two tables with the same name, unique names.  You can see more examples at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Got it. Wish I could select both answers as the one that solved my problem though ...anyway, thanks again, nice day to you Sir.